# netlink_broadcast fail with return value -3

Tags: networking, kernel, kernel-module, broadcast, netlink

I can't broadcast netlink message to userspace by the following code. However, I can't find anything wrong. My userspace program can recieve broadcast message of other types, for example `sock_fd=socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);`, but not my type `SYSHOOK_NL_NUM`.

I think that bugs hide in my kernel code. Can anyone figure out what's wrong? Thanks.

```
   syshook_nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, SYSHOOK_NL_NUM, 1, NULL, NULL, THIS_MODULE);
 skb = alloc_skb(NLMSG_SPACE(nl_send_len), GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(!skb) {
        error = -ENOMEM;
        goto err;
    }    
    nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)skb->data;
    nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(nl_send_len);
    nlh->nlmsg_pid = 0; 
    nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;
    nlh = nlmsg_put(skb, 0, 0, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(nl_send_len) - sizeof (struct nlmsghdr), 0);
    NETLINK_CB(skb).pid = 0;
    NETLINK_CB(skb).dst_group = 1;
    error = netlink_broadcast(syshook_nl_sk, skb, 0, 1, GFP_KERNEL);
```

Userspace code that receive broadcast messages from kernel.

```
 sock_fd=socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_TEST);
   // sock_fd=socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 15);
    if(sock_fd < 0) {
        printf("create nl failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));

    src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_addr.nl_pid = 100;  /* self pid */
    /* interested in group 1<<0 */
    src_addr.nl_groups = 1;
 //   setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buffersize, sizeof(buffersize));  
    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr));
    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));

    iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;
    iov.iov_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    char buf[1024] = {0};
    printf("begin to recvmsg jiang \n");
    int rcvlen;
    while (1) {
    /* Read message from kernel */

        rcvlen = recv(sock_fd, &buf, sizeof(buf), 0);  
 //   rcvlen = recvmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);

    printf("--%d--%s\n",rcvlen, buf);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo make it works. Seems the code is OK.